# Treating remote control events in every view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have 2 ViewControllers in my Application.

ViewController1 plays audio and ViewController2 shows some text.

I want to use remote controls to control the audio when I'm in ViewController2. For instance, the user is in ViewController2 and wants to stop the audio.

My code:

ViewController1.m WORKS PERFECTLY

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)receivedEvent
{
    MARK;
    if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

        switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                DLog(@"remotecontrol_toggle");
                [self togglePlayPause];
                break;

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause:
                DLog(@"remotecontrol_pause");
                [self pause];
                break;

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay:
                DLog(@"remotecontrol_play");
                [self play];
                break;

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop:
                DLog(@"remotecontrol_stop");
                [self stop];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, what's the best way to put this all together? Do I have to treat the events in ViewController2?

I know that in AppDelegate.m, I can do this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    MARK;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    MARK;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
}
```

This way, my application controls the remote control in every view, but that doesn't solve my problem because the received events aren't treated in ViewController2.

But I can't treat received events in AppDelegate.m, so I'll have to treat the events in every ViewController?

I'm new to iOS Development, don't know if I'm thinking right here.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to subclass UIApplication and treat the event there.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to pass a reference to ViewController1 to ViewController2 when you are creating it. Easiest way is to have an init method that takes the reference...

```
- (id) initWithController:(UIViewController*)controller
{
   self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _controller1 = controller;
    }
    return self;
}
```

then use the same method for receiving events but call out to your ViewController1 to handle them...

```
- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)receivedEvent
{

    if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

        switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                DLog(@"remotecontrol_toggle");
                [self.controller1 togglePlayPause];
                break;

            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 solutions 2 fail 1 is correct.

I am lazzy now to explain why other 2 fail. So here is my implementation logic ( I did with audio me too )

There is a model, there are several controller, and there are a few views. First get familiar with ModelViewController patter, because here you need to do a multi controller and multi view :)

In one class , not need to be UIViewController store the data, that is the "Model" . Here you have the song name, the volume level, the cat color, the dog shoes size, whatever else.

Now implement a couple of controllers. Those classes set some property values for the same model instance ( your example text ) .

In other classes you can implement even receivers: the model has setter functions and fill fire events for event listeners, which are subscribed. - well, this explained as Java, but in iOS is the same.

Those property change event listeners can be embedded into a new controller or a new view.

Easy to say, harder to implement correctly for a beginner.

I gave an idea and keywords what to search. Hoping it will help you.

There are 2 easier solutions, but it will not work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for now, I don't think I need that complexity. My app is simple, I just want to treat events in my currently environment.